# How can I call functions at href in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

When I run this source then it showed me just

[Kakao is not defined]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA7VI.png

My sources are like this

in 『nuxt.config.js』

```
export default {
  // Global page headers (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head)
  head: {
    script: [
      { src: 'https://developers.kakao.com/sdk/js/kakao.js'},
    ]
  },
}
```

in 『./pages/login.vue』

```
<template>
   <a :href="loginWithKakao()">
     <img
       src="https://k.kakaocdn.net/14/dn/btqCn0WEmI3/nijroPfbpCa4at5EIsjyf0/o.jpg"
       width="222"
     />
   </a>          
</template>
<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      visible: true,
      account: '',
      password: '',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState('store', { logo: (state) => state.logo }),
  },
  methods: {
    loginWithKakao() {
      Kakao.Auth.login({
        success: function (response) {
          // console.log("Kakao.Auth.login - success response ->", response);
          Kakao.API.request({
            url: '/v2/user/me',
            success: function (response) {
              console.log(response)
            },
            fail: function (error) {
              console.log(error)
            },
          })
        },
        fail: function (error) {
          console.log(error)
        },
      })
    },       
  },
  mounted(){
    // Initialize the SDK. Please set the JavaScript key for the app you want to use.
    Kakao.init('JavaScript key');

    // Determines whether to initialize the SDK.
    console.log('Kakao.isInitialized() >>', Kakao.isInitialized());
  },
}
</script>
```

When I used this in html, it worked

```
<a id="custom-login-btn" href="javascript:loginWithKakao()">
  <img
    src="https://k.kakaocdn.net/14/dn/btqCn0WEmI3/nijroPfbpCa4at5EIsjyf0/o.jpg"
    width="222"
  />
</a>
```

As I know, we can use `href="javascript:your_function()"` in html as `:href="your_function()"` in Vue.js

Or are there some ways something others?

Comment: you have import `Kakao` in your file.

`import Kakao from 'Kakao'` like this.

Comment: I added 'kakao script js file' in nuxt.config.js.
Anyway i tried to write ```import Kakao from 'Kakao'``` in <script> part but it didn`t work. Console said 'This dependency was not found'

Comment: install from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/kakao . and add click event instead of href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a Button instead of an `<a>` tag, as it is obviously not a link?
However, either way you should just add a click handler to invoke the function:

```html
<a @click="loginWithKakao()">
  <img
  
  src="https://k.kakaocdn.net/14/dn/btqCn0WEmI3/nijroPfbpCa4at5EIsjyf0/o.jpg"
    width="222"
  />
</a>
```

Comment: When I used the Button then I could see that the extra outlines of button tag were revealed, not only ```https://k.kakaocdn.net/14/dn/btqCn0WEmI3/nijroPfbpCa4at5EIsjyf0/o.jpg```.
By the way, then we can't use :href for calling a function in vue.js?